# Writing a .tgz file using PHP with 100,000+ entries, but avoiding individual file writes

Tags: php, gzip, tar, phar

I am trying to write a .tgz file containing tens if not hundreds of thousands of file entries, the contents of each of which have come from a string in a database. Each file entry is about 2-5k of data.

I want to avoid doing this without having to write the files out first. Currently I have PHP creating a traditional directory structure, writing files, then making a tgz from that at the very end using a shellexec.

The disk we are using is slow and so writing tens of thousands of files is taking ages. Even running a prototype on another machine with a fast disk using a tmpfs ramdisk and lots of CPU, I get a rate of about 100-200 file entries per second, which feels slow - half an hour for 150,000 files in a directory structure. Once that has been written, the actual conversion from the native OS directory structure to tgz is not problematic.

I was hoping to use PharData to do the writing. However, PharData::addFromString seems to do a file write as soon as the file is added, rather than an an Open->Add->Writeout pattern.

Can anyone suggest any strategies here?

The eventual tgz file is then to be made available for download, and will not be refreshed often. But because there are a series of these files to be created, having to wait 30-60+ minutes just to package it becomes quite a blocker.

Comment: Can you give some context about what performance improvement you're after, and what the file is for? How often is a refreshed file required? If this is a file that is made available for download on a website, for example, would you need it refreshed more than every half an hour? (I agree that 200 entries/sec sounds slow, but I imagine compression to be a CPU-intensive process).

Comment: If you are not bothered about a larger output file size, try turning down the compression level. The `gzip` command really does have a `--fast` option, try that?

Comment: It would certainly be interesting to compare the workload when you disable compression to identify where the performance problems are. I suspect your biggest win would come from using a different structure to hold the data - hence what is the scope for changing that?

Comment: I've added some clarifications - the problem is not the compression stage, it's the current directory creation stage *before* compression, but I'm hoping there is a better way to deal with this fundamentally. I've also clarified about the use of the file - see new last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php gzopen/gzwrite/gzclose functions directly, and format your own tar headers, followed by the entry data.  There is an example on the [php gzwrite documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzwrite.php).

Comment: Sadly, this does seem to have the same problem - it writes out the whole archive after each invocation of addString, rather than allowing multiple addStrings to be done and then write the file. Accordingly, this would involve 100,000+ file writes in addition to 100,000+ compression calculations, so even worse than the directory structure approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, however I'll try to answer it.
Phar buffering was supported at least with PHP 5.3:

> [`Phar::startBuffering()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.startbuffering.php)
> Start buffering Phar write operations, do not modify the Phar object on disk

> [`Phar::stopBuffering()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.stopbuffering.php)
> Stop buffering write requests to the Phar archive, and save changes to disk

---

A small example on how that would look like:

```
<?php
$phar = new Phar('bundle.phar');
$phar->startBuffering();
// ... adding files and contents ...
$phar->setStub('<?php __HALT_COMPILER();');
$phar->stopBuffering();
```